# How to implement images into text editor in Nextjs trying to make a blog app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, prisma, web-development-server

```
 model Post {id        String    @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")createdAt DateTime  @default(now())slug      String    @uniquetitle     Stringdesc      Stringimg       Stringviews     Int       @default(0)catSlug   String
```

```
cat       Category?  @relation(fields: [catSlug], references: [slug])userEmail Stringuser      User      @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email])comments  Comment[]catViews  Int       @map("_catViews") @default(0)}
```

above is my prisma mongodb post schema , i use nextjs prisma mongodb firebase and here is my write jsx component (text editor):

```
const WritePage = () => {const { status } = useSession();const router = useRouter();

const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);const [file, setFile] = useState(null);const [media, setMedia] = useState([]);const [value, setValue] = useState("");const [title, setTitle] = useState("");const [catSlug, setCatSlug] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {// import Quillimport("react-quill").then((Quill) => {import("react-quill/dist/quill.bubble.css");

});

}, []);useEffect(() => {const storage = getStorage(app);const upload = () => {const name = new Date().getTime() + file.name;const storageRef = ref(storage, name);

  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {
      const progress =
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");         
    },
    (error) => {},
    () => {
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
        setMedia((prevMedia) => [...prevMedia, downloadURL]);
      });
    }
  );
};

file && upload();

}, [file]);

if (status === "loading") {return <div className={styles.loading}>Loading...</div>;}

if (status === "unauthenticated") {router.push("/");}{media && (<div className={styles.mediaPreview}></div>)}const slugify = (str) =>str.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/[^\w\s-]/g, "").replace(/[\s_-]+/g, "-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "");

const handleSubmit = async () => {const res = await fetch("/api/posts", {method: "POST",body: JSON.stringify({title,desc: value,img: media,slug: slugify(title),catSlug: catSlug || "coding", //If not selected, choose the general category}),

});

if (res.status === 200) {
  const data = await res.json();
  router.push(`/posts/${data.slug}`);
}

};

return (<div className={styles.container}><inputtype="text"placeholder="Title"className={styles.input}onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}/>
        
<input
    type="text"
    className={styles.select}
    onChange={(e) => setCatSlug(e.target.value)}
    placeholder="Enter category"
  />

  <div className={styles.editor}>
    <button className={styles.button} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
      <Image src="/plus.png" alt="" width={16} height={16} />
    </button>
    {open && (
      <div className={styles.add}>
        <input
          type="file"
          id="image"
          onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
          style={{ display: "none" }}
        />
        <button className={styles.addButton}>
          <label htmlFor="image">
            <Image src="/image.png" alt="" width={16} height={16} />
          </label>
        </button>

      </div>
    )}
    <ReactQuill
      className={styles.textArea}
   
      theme="bubble"
      value={value}
      onChange={setValue}
      placeholder="Tell me...."
    />
  </div>
  <button className={styles.publish} onClick={handleSubmit}>
    Publish
  </button>
</div>
);};
```

it adds a single image at the top of the blog post but i want to be able to add images anywhere i want as i write a content but i dont know how to implement that if i were to make an array of imageurls it doesnt work besides how am i gonna display those images in the right order ? so should i add it into description field as rich text editor but then i couldnt achieve that im kind of confused right know can somebody help ? any idea?

and this is how it displays published posts again i need to display some images inside content too:

```
const getData = async (slug) => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${slug}?`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed");
  }

  return res.json();
};

const SinglePage = async ({ params }) => {
  const { slug } = params;

  const data = await getData(slug);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.infoContainer}>
        <div className={styles.textContainer}>
          <h1 className={styles.title}>{data?.title}</h1>
          <div className={styles.user}>
            {data?.user?.image && (
              <div className={styles.userImageContainer}>
                <Image src={data.user.image} alt="" layout="fill" className={styles.avatar} />
              </div>
            )}
            <span className={styles.username}>{data?.user.name}</span>
            <span className={styles.date}>{data.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        {data?.img && (
          <div className={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image src={data.img} alt="" layout="fill" className={styles.image} />
           
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* CONTENT */}
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <div className={styles.post}>
          <ReactMarkdown source={data?.desc} />
          <div className={styles.comment}>
            <Comments postSlug={slug} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

i tried to make img as string of array but even if i achieve it,that wouldnt do. i tried to add quill toolbar images but i also couldnt make that work .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.